# How to avoid packet loss on server application restart?

Tags: python, linux, web-services, tcp, network-programming

A typical situation with a server/web application is that the application needs to be shut down and restarted to implement an upgrade.

**What are the possible/common schemes (and available software) to avoid losing data that clients sent to the server during the short time the application was gone?**

An example scheme that could work is: For a simple web server where the client connects to port 80, rather than the client connecting directly to the web server application, there could be a simple application in between that listens to port 80 and seamlessly forwards/returns data to/from the "Actual" web server application (on some other port).  When the web server needs to be shut down and restarted, the relay app could detect this and buffer all incoming data until the webserver comes back to life.  This way there is *always* an application listening to port 80 and data is never lost (within buffer-size and time reason, of course).  Does such a simple intermediate buffer-on-recipient-unavailable piece of software exist already?

I'm mostly interested in solutions for a single application instance and not one where there are multiple instances (in which case a clever rolling update scheme could be used), but in the interests of having a full answer set, any response would be great!

Comment: Then what happens when the server hosting the 'in-between' app goes down?

Comment: @Michael Kent - for that one example, the service would obviously go down.  However, the buffer-capable relay application would be single-minded and not require updates to bring it down, or at least MUCH less frequently than the main application.  Crashes are a whole other story... I'm only interested in known/scheduled updates/maintenance.

Comment: Then your 'in-between' app, which will queue its input when the destination app is down, is a candidate solution.  You might want to look around before you reinvent the wheel, though.  I believe RabbitMQ is often used for this purpose, but might be overkill.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this, have multiple application servers behind a load balancer. Before bringing one down, ensure the load balancer is not sending it new clients. Bring it down, traffic will go to the other applications servers, and when it comes back up traffic will begin getting sent to it again.

If you have only one application server, simply 'buffering' network traffic is a poor solution. When the server comes back up, it has none of the TCP state information anymore and the old incoming connections have nowhere to go anyway.

Comment: True on the loss of TCP state, although this can be managed by signalling the relay process that an upgrade is imminent, so start buffering!  Once in-process sockets are completed, the restart can happen.  This, of course, relies on "short" connection lifetimes, or the buffer could explode.  If this fails (max buffer or timeout reached), then you either pull the ripcord on buffering and eat the downtime, or go the other way and flush the buffer and abort the upgrade "upgrade not possible right now due to socket hog").

Comment: I forgot to add that the multiple applications thing is not possible in my particular case (although my question is general).  I'm on the verge of prototyping my hypothetical buffering relay to check performance, but would prefer to not have to reinvent it as I'm betting it will be tricky to get to be reliable and fast.

Comment: This 'TCP buffering' solution is extremely complex and prone to failure in comparison to a load balanced solution. I have never heard of a buffering solution before, however tens of thousands of load balancers are deployed all the time.